# CSS: An element with a hanging indent and a hidden overflow that doesn't cut it off?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to make an element with a [hanging indent](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/hanginde.htm), along with a hidden overflow that does not hide said indent.

This demonstrates my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Skofo/qgd2p/

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, swap the `margin-left: 15px;` for `padding-left: 15px;` on your `li` elements.

I've only checked this in chrome, mind. You might have to set `box-sizing` to something consistent to make it work cross-browser, like `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 2):

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saSna/

Is this the result you want to achieve?

I've added 15px padding to `li`, and removed `:first-child` so both `ul`'s have the same styles:

```
ul li {
    width:120px;
    text-indent:-15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```